# Save success not working with parse.com object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, parse.js

I have been messing around trying to save data from a web form and cannot get the standard validation to return. Thinking this is some sort of async problem that I am just not getting. Saving objects with the parse.com api is built off of backbone.js, so it is pretty similar to that. For some reason I can save my data to my database no problems, but when I try to introduce some sort of validation it gets messed up. Looking for some info on how to properly get a success validation back from the server. Right now it hits error every time, and seems to kill the server from saving data.

Below is the code that executes on submit. I have shown the three ways I have tried saving data.

```
$("#f1").submit(function(event) {
        var NewRes = Parse.Object.extend("Customer");
        var newRes = new NewRes();

        newRes.set("FirstName", "Ricky");
        newRes.set("LastName", "Bobby");

        //works every time, but I have no return validating it
        newRes.save();

        //saving with callback options, doesn't save anything to the database and hits error message
        newRes.save(null, {
            wait: true,
            success: function(newRes, response) {
                alert("success" + response.message);
            },
            error: function(newRes, response) {
                alert("errorcode: " + response.code + "  Message: " + response.message);
            }
        });

        //saving with promises, doesn't save anything and hits error message
        newRes.save().then(function(response) {
            alert("success");
        }, function(error) {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
```

Here are the results of the error message given below:

```
errorcode: 100  Message: XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}
```

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript  hav u look at this one?  your code looks ok but without details from the error block, its hard to guess

Comment: So you're saying that save() works (saves the object), but save().then(... doesn't save the object?  That's surprising.  How would save know the difference between save(); and save().anything ?

Comment: Yes, only "object.save();" works all the time. "object.save(options):" and "object.save().then(function(promises callbacks)" do not save anything. Then they always hit the error option. Sometimes however, the will save a record. This is what makes me think it is a async issue.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and I found that making my function (e.g. `$("#f1").submit(function(event) {` return false fixed it.

Comment: So adding "return false" does fix the issue of the error statement always being hit. However, then the form doesn't submit and then the record isn't saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason none of this was working is because the form.submit() function was finishing before any of the parse.com asynchronous functions were complete. In order to prevent this I used the preventdefault method to stop the form from submitting. Then I used location.reload() to refresh the page after my parse.com requests have either finished successful or failed.

```
$("#f1").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var NewRes = Parse.Object.extend("Customer");
    var newRes = new NewRes();

    newRes.set("FirstName", "Ricky");
    newRes.set("LastName", "Bobby");

    //saving with promises
    newRes.save().then(function(response) {
        alert("success");
        location.reload(); //refreshes the form
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert("error");
        location.reload();
    });
});
```